# Issue with "rake" and won't connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app i've been working on for a while and it was always working and testing fine. Then for some reason today when I tried rake db:migrate I get the message below. I have started using git recently. Whether that has anything to do with it I don't know.

Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.5.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

If i type bundle exec rake db:migrate it seems to complete the migration the issue now is that in the new view when the user hits the submit button the create action isn't called. So the data isn't entered into the database.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Jerome, did you try to run bundle update?

Comment: Seems you are having two different problems. In the first case you have to make sure that all of your gems have the correct version. In the second case your form may point to the wrong action (but need more information to see what might be wrong there). However, both problems don't seem to be related.

Comment: Be careful running bundle update, as suggested in comments, it will potentially upgrade all your gems, which can leave you in a mess for debugging, if things break. You can update individual gems of course.

Answer (score 8):

You have to run `bundle update` on the terminal. I was also facing the same issue but after bundle update everything got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

1. I used existing rvm gemset for new project
2. After `bundle install` (for new project) I had `rake (10.5.0)` in new project's Gemfile.lock
3. Old project is more important so I uninstalled rake 10.5.0 `rvm gemset use <gemsetname>; gem uninstall rake` + select 10.5.0 (asked in console)
4. `rake (10.4.2)` in new project's Gemfile.lock